# Toggling WAL usage within same VM?

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm one of the developers of the [Hawk model indexing](https://github.com/mondo-project/mondo-hawk) tool. Our tool indexes XMI models into graphs in order to speed up later queries, and it needs to toggle back and forth between "batch insert" and "transactional update" modes. "batch insert" is used the first time we notice a new file in a directory, and from then on we use "transactional update" mode to keep its graph in sync.

Our recently added [OrientDB 2.1.4 backend](https://github.com/mondo-project/mondo-hawk/blob/master/org.hawk.orientdb/src/org/hawk/orientdb/OrientDatabase.java) uses the getTx()/getNoTx() methods in OrientGraphFactory to get the appropriate OrientGraph/OrientGraphNoTx instances. However, we aren't getting very good throughput when compared to Neo4j. Indexing set0.xmi takes 90s when placing the WAL in a Linux ramdisk with OrientDB, while it takes 22s with our Neo4j backend in the same conditions (machine + OS + JDK). We're using these additional settings to try and reduce times:

- Increased WAL cache size to 10000
- Disable sync on page flush
- Save only dirty objects
- Use massive insert intent
- Disable transactional log
- Disable MVCC
- Disable validation
- Use lightweight edges when possible

We've thought of disabling the WAL when entering "batch insert" mode, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to toggle that on and off. It appears it can only be set once at program startup and that's it. We've tried explicitly closing the underlying storage so the USE_WAL flag will be read once more while reopening the storage, but that only results in NullPointerExceptions and other random errors.

Any pointers on how we could toggle the WAL, or improve performance beyond that would be greatly appreciated.

Update: We've switched to using the raw document API and marking dirty nodes/edges ourselves and we're now hitting 55 seconds, but the WAL problem still persists. Also tried 2.2.0-beta, but it actually took longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this ourselves. Leaving this in case it might help someone :-). We've hit 30 seconds after many internal improvements in our backend (still using the raw doc API) and switching to OrientDB 2.0.15, and we found the way to toggle the Write Ahead Log ourselves. This works for us (db is our ODatabaseDocumentTx instance):

```
private void reopenWithWALSetTo(final boolean useWAL) {
    db.getStorage().close(true, false);
    db.close();
    OGlobalConfiguration.USE_WAL.setValue(useWAL);
    db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbURL);
    db.open("admin", "admin");
}
```

I was being silly and thought I had to close the DB first and then the storage, but it turns out that wasn't the case :-). It's necessary to use the two-arg version of the ODatabaseDocumentTx#close method, as the no-arg version basically does nothing for the OAbstractPaginatedStorage implementation used through plocal:// URLs.

Comment: We could put this in a higher level API. Opening a new issue for that: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5254